# Display table with sqllite database values in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to display table in the ui with the data is coming from sqllite database table. How can I achieve in Android? By the following I am creating the table with static content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<TableLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*">  
    <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/textView9"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"  
            android:textSize="18dp"  
            android:text="Weather Table"  
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  
    <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text=""></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
            android:text="Feb 7"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"  
            android:text="Feb 8"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"  
            android:text="Feb 9"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"  
            android:text="Feb 10"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Feb 11"  
            android:id="@+id/textView1"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  
    <TableRow  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Day High"  
            android:id="@+id/textView2"  
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/textView3"  
            android:text="28°F"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="26°F"  
            android:id="@+id/textView4"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="23°F"  
            android:id="@+id/textView5"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="17°F"  
            android:id="@+id/textView6"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="19°F"  
            android:id="@+id/textView7"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  
    <TableRow  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView  
            android:text="Day Low"  
            android:id="@+id/textView2"  
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="15°F"  
            android:id="@+id/textView3"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="14°F"  
            android:id="@+id/textView4"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="3°F"  
            android:id="@+id/textView5"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="5°F"  
            android:id="@+id/textView6"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:text="6°F"  
            android:id="@+id/textView7"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  
    <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/textView8"  
            android:text="Conditions"  
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>  
        <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"  
            android:src="@drawable/hot"></ImageView>  
        <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"  
            android:src="@drawable/pt_cloud"></ImageView>  
        <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"  
            android:src="@drawable/snow"></ImageView>  
        <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"  
            android:src="@drawable/lt_snow"></ImageView>  
        <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"  
            android:src="@drawable/pt_sun"></ImageView>  
    </TableRow>  
</TableLayout>
```

Please see once how can I append dynamic values to that rows in Android and display table in the Android front end app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a table like the following one in xml,

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/rows_table"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="color or drawable"
android:shrinkColumns="*"  
android:stretchColumns="*"/>
```

and declare the table in your code,

```
RowsTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.rows_table);
```

and you can do the following in `AsyncTask PostExcute` or somewhere you wish to,

```
// entries are the no.of that you decided to print dynamically.
    int rows;
                    for (rows=0;rows<entries.length();rows++)
                {

                    TableRow trTwo = new TableRow(Activity.this);
                    trTwo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
// Here you can get the cursor data , which is going to be displayed in the coloumns.
//entriesVar is the coloumn data.
                    for(int coloumn = 2; coloumn < entriesVar.length; coloumn++)
                    {
                    //Your database values
                    if (coloumn == 1)
                    {

                        //Any Header options, If you wish to show any table headers

                    }


                    String questionable = "sometext";
                TextView txtTwo = new TextView(ReportsActivity.this);

                txtTwo.setText(questionable);
                txtTwo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            txtTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txtTwo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            txtTwo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_border_new);
            txtTwo.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
            trTwo.addView(txtTwo);// Binding Text To Row
            }
           // Adding View To Table
           RowsTable.addView(trTwo, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
          }
```

Comment: i have all the data in cusor how can i append forthis through any loop for repitations ?

Comment: dbadapter.open();
    Cursor cursor=dbadapter.fetchordersdata(custid);
    int count=cursor.getCount();
    String ordernum=cursor.getString(0);
    
        String pId=cursor.getString(1);
    String Pqty=cursor.getString(2);
    System.out.println("*********COUNT::::"+count);
    System.out.println("*********LINE::::"+ordernum);
 System.out.println("*********PID::::"+pId);
 System.out.println("*********PQTY::::"+Pqty);

Comment: these are my db values how can i set in the above code ? thanks for ur reply

Comment: So you need to display ordernum,pid,pqty in every rows. right?

Comment: So loop your cursor here for(int coloumn = 2; coloumn < entriesVar.length; coloumn++). And add the cursor values in the newly created Textview txtTwo.

Comment: orderno   productid   productqty   custid
1         1000001      2            00010
2         1000001      5            00010

Comment: then create four textView like the txtTwo and print all at a same time then loop it for next row...

Comment: @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bycustomers);
    
    custid="00001201";
    dbadapter=new DBAdapter(this);
    
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    
    dbadapter.open();
    Cursor cursor=dbadapter.fetchordersdata(custid);
    int count=cursor.getCount();
    String ordernum=cursor.getString(0);
    
    
 
    }

Comment: loop the cursor upto cursor.getCount(), and place this (String ordernum = cursor.getString(0)) ordernum in the textview created inside the tablerow. Try it first then place other strings like getString(1), getString(2), getString(3), in the newly created textviews...